# Perform action every once in a while

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, sampling

I am currently trying (Python 2.7) to set an action to be performed with a fixed sampling frequency (i.e. every x milliseconds). However, I am facing inaccurate results. With the code bellow (sampling frequency of 1000Hz, code running for 5 seconds) I would expect to have 5 * 10000 samples. Instead, I'm getting lower values. I would like to have a sampling frequency of 5000Hz at best, but I would also be happy with 1000Hz.

Can anyone help me?

```
import datetime

count = 0
loop_start_time = start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

while datetime.datetime.now() - loop_start_time <= datetime.timedelta(0,5,0): #loop for 5 seconds
    if datetime.datetime.now() - start_time >= datetime.timedelta(0,0,1000): #perform an action every 1000 microseconds (1 millisecond, 0.1 seconds)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        count = count + 1
print count
```

Best regards,
T2

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using datetime rather than a threading timer?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects - for more detail. You can have an outer timer which counts 5000 milliseconds (5 sec) and within that another timer which runs every 1ms.

Comment: Hello @Andrew. Many thanks for your answer. I didnt know about threading timer! Does it handle up to 5000Hz?

Comment: Hello Andrew. I'm having trouble using timer objects, as it only runs once. How do I make it to run until I make it stop?
This is my current test code:
`import threading

def hello():
    print "hello, world"
    
t = threading.Timer(5, hello)
t.start()`
If I put the thread code in a loop, it prints values at random (fast) times.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
import time
import threading

total_time = 5
increment_time = .1
is_running = False
count = 0

def incrementCounter(): 
  global count
  global is_running
  is_running = True
  threading.Timer(increment_time, incrementCounter).start()
  count += 1
  # Any additional code should be put here

end_time = time.time() + total_time
while time.time() < end_time:
  if not is_running:
    incrementCounter()


print count
```

Output for this I am getting ~50.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it is very helpful. However, this is not reliable enough. With a higher sampling frequency (e.g. increment_time = .01, 100Hz) I get 325 samples, instead of 500. :(
So far, `datetime` gives the best results (up to 100Hz).

Comment: With the code you posted above, at time delta 5 seconds and 1 second respectfully I am getting output of 4. With `Timer` it will consistently output 5 with the same configuration. I'm not sure `datetime` is very reliable even at lower intervals.